# session[:id] variable not being picked up within another route from sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am following this tutorial here on setting up a user login https://learn.co/lessons/sinatra-user-auth

It says that in order to save a `session[:id]` in my route I would do something like this:

```
post '/login' do
  @user = User.get_id(params['email'],params['password'])
  session[:id] = @user # equals a numeric value of the matching user
  redirect '/home'
end
```

however, when i get to my `/home` route I am no longer able to access the `session[:id]` that was set in my `/login` route, it returns `nil`

```
# this doesnt return the session id
# consequently I cant lookup my user records
get '/home' do
  @user = User.object(session[:id]) # looks up user object with numeric value
  erb :home
end
```

I have tried enabling sessions in my config controller, that didnt work either

```
module Controllers

  class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

    # . . . .

    configure :production, :development do
      enable :sessions, :logging 
    end

  end 

end
```

how do I make my app persist the `session[:id]` between routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enable :sessions after you require your sinatra gem in your sinatra app? Not in your controller

Comment: Meant add as a comment above now wont let me delete it im on my phone not sure how too